# My tensorflow neural network accuracy does not change

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I wants to build a neural network for [Student Admission dataset](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv)(admit, gre, gpa, rank)
I made admit and rank one-hot as follows

```
    one_hot_data = pd.concat([data, pd.get_dummies(data['rank'], prefix='rank')], axis=1)
    one_hot_data = pd.concat([one_hot_data, pd.get_dummies(data['admit'], prefix='admit')], axis=1)
    
    # Drop the previous rank column
    data = one_hot_data.drop('rank', axis=1)
    data = one_hot_data.drop('admit', axis=1)
    print(data.shape)
```

I split the data using `train_test_split` and scale using `minmax_scale`
But neural network is as folows

```
n_features = X_train.shape[1]
n_labels = y_train.shape[1]

features = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_features])
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_labels])

w = [
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_features, 16)), name='Weights_layer_0'),
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((16, 4)), name='Weights_layer_1'),
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((4, n_labels)), name='Weights_layer_2'),
]

n_layers = len(w)
b = [
    tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16), name='Bias_layer_0'),
    tf.Variable(tf.zeros(4), name='Bias_layer_1'),
    tf.Variable(tf.zeros(n_labels), name='Bias_layer_2'),
]
def neural_network(input, weights, biases):
    for i in range(n_layers-1):
        layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(input if i==0 else layer, weights[i]),biases[i])
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
        # layer = tf.nn.dropout(layer, keep_prob=0.6)
    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer, weights[-1]),biases[-1])
    return out_layer

loss_ = []
res = []
prediction = neural_network(features, w, b)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=labels))
optim = tf.train.AdadeltaOptimizer(0.0001).minimize(loss)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
with tf.device('/gpu'):
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for i in range(10):
            for m,n in zip(X_train_batches, y_train_batches):
                _, l = sess.run([optim, loss],feed_dict={features: m, labels: n})
            loss_.append(l)

            acc = sess.run([accuracy], feed_dict={features: X_train, labels: y_train})
            print(i, acc)
        test_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={features: X_test, labels: y_test})
        print(test_accuracy)
        res = sess.run(neural_network(features,w,b),feed_dict={features: X})
```

But accuracy doesn't change

```
0 [0.4857143]
1 [0.4857143]
2 [0.4857143]
3 [0.4857143]
4 [0.4857143]
5 [0.4857143]
6 [0.4857143]
7 [0.4857143]
8 [0.4857143]
9 [0.4857143]
10 [0.4857143]
0.5333333
```

and loss stays the same

```
[0.5546836, 0.5546756, 0.5546678, 0.55466014, 0.55465263, 0.5546452, 0.55463773, 0.55463034, 0.5546232, 0.5546159, 0.5546088, 0.5546016, 0.5545944, 0.5545874, 0.5545803, 0.5545734, 0.55456626, 0.5545592, 0.5545522, 0.5545452]
```

What is missing? Is my neural network correct? [Full code](https://pastebin.com/UTErxJeq)

Comment: Increase your learning rate and generally run a proper gridsearch on your hyperparameters.

Comment: @runDOSrun Are you sure  that is related to hyperparameters?

Comment: The question is rather if you've eliminated hyperparameters as a potential explanation :) It  should always be the first thing you investigate once your code runs successfully. One of the parameters seems to cause extremely small gradients (note that your loss does NOT stay the same, it just changes VERY slowly). This is most often caused by a small learning rate.

Comment: Indeed, you are not looking for someone being *sure* what the problem is, especially since we cannot reproduce it ourselves; at best, you are looking for reasonable advice based on what you have posted.

Comment: I have played a lot with those parameters before sending it here

Answer (score 1):

There may be many possible causes here (and we don't have your data), but, according to my experience, a frequent mistake in such cases is initializing the weights with the default argument of `stddev=1.0` in `tf.random_normal()` (see the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/normal)), as you do here.

A `stddev=1.0` is a **huge** value, and it alone can make your NN go astray. Change it to `stddev=0.01` for all your initial weights:

```
w = [
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((n_features, 16), stddev=0.01), name='Weights_layer_0'),
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((16, 4), stddev=0.01), name='Weights_layer_1'),
    tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((4, n_labels), stddev=0.01), name='Weights_layer_2'),
    ]
```

Other than that, as already suggested in the comments, a learning rate of `0.0001` seems way too small here (given how slowly the loss is decreasing); experiment with higher values (`0.01 - 0.001`).

Comment: Didn't made much Now accuracy 0 [0.6785714]
1 [0.69285715]
2 [0.69285715]
3 [0.69285715]
4 [0.69285715]
5 [0.69285715]
6 [0.69285715]
7 [0.69285715]
8 [0.69285715]
9 [0.69285715]
10 [0.69285715]

Comment: @AliReza an improvement from ~ 0.48 (random guessing) to ~ 0.69 (+21%) is neither negligible nor trivial - it is the difference between "no learning" and "learning something indeed". As already said, there are multiple possible causes here, and it sure seems like the answer addressed one of them.

Comment: Don't look at the exact amount its all repeating!

Comment: @AliReza have you increased the learning rate, as already suggested? Your *loss* is indeed decreasing (albeit very slowly); "*I have played a lot with those parameters*" does not say much in itself - with `stddev=1.0`, no matter how much you played you would not get any meaningful results.

Comment: Yes, I did played 0.1 to 0.00001 for learning rate.

Comment: Isn't there any problem in my implementation of nn?